# How do I implement soft delete for acr using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, acr

I have a pre-existing ACR and I need to enable soft-deletion policy  using terraform. I don't want to use null-resource, is there any other way I can achieve this?

```
resource "null_resource" "soft_delete_policy" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az acr config soft-delete update -r MyRegistry --days 7 --status Enabled"
  }
```

Comment: Why can you not use a resource for the acr instead?

Comment: Just for information, the soft-delete option in container registry still not available, and here is the thread that are having discussions https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/18408

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AzAPI provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerregistry/registries?pivots=deployment-language-terraform):

```
    softDeletePolicy = {
      retentionDays = int
      status = "string"
    }
```

First, run `az acr show -g <your-resource-group> -n <your-acr-name> -o json` to get the container registry's resource configuration in JSON format.

Then, construct an azapi_resource in your Terraform configuration using the relevant bits of the JSON:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "your_acr" {
  type = "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-11-01-preview"
  name = "youracr"
  location = "westus"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.your_resource_group.id
  tags = { }
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      adminUserEnabled = false
...
```

Next, import the AzAPI resource into your Terraform configuration:

```
terraform import azapi_resource.your_acr /subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<your-resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/youracr
```

Update the AzAPI resource in the Terraform config to set soft delete policy:

```
softDeletePolicy = {
  retentionDays = 7
  status = "enabled"
}
```

Finally, apply the change via `terraform apply`